# Multiple path.exists callbacks, how to know which file the return status is for?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The node.js built in library function for checking if a file exists asynchronously only supplies a boolean "exists" to the callback. I need to check if multiple files exists which seems problematic. How do I know for which file the response is?

Is the execution order of the callbacks guaranteed or something? Or can I supply the index to the callback somehow that I haven't thought of? Obviously my attempt here with "var k" failed. :/

```
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys');

var paths = new Array();
paths.push('file_0');
paths.push('file_1');
paths.push('file_2');

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++)
{
    var k = i;
    path.exists(paths[i], function(exists) {
        var j = i;
        sys.puts("One of the files has this status: " + exists + " but which one?");
        sys.puts("j is: "+j); 
        sys.puts("k is: "+k);
    });
}
```

The output from a run is:

```
$ node test.js
One of the files has this status: false but which one?
j is: 3
k is: 2
One of the files has this status: false but which one?
j is: 3
k is: 2
One of the files has this status: false but which one?
j is: 3
k is: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Javascript hoists all variable declarations to the top of the function, which is stupid and unintuitive.  Some workarounds: [JavaScript variable binding and loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676362/)

Comment: Using "(function() { my loop code })();" worked nicely, thanks!