# Shared data problem

Tags: javascript, multithreading, concurrency

I have a code like this:

```
var increment = 200;

for (var j=0; j<10; j++){

  var print = function(){ console.log("===== J ===== "+j); }

  setTimeout(print, increment); 

  increment+= 200;

}
```

Console always print 10. I think that could be for statement and setTimeout are executed in different threads. How i can do to print the correct value of j?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't see anything in your code that would print only "10" and there is no variable `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard binding issue, you can find a lot of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676362/javascript-variable-binding-and-loop) on stackoverflow.

Basically, it is using one 'j' for all values. Try this instead:

```
function getBoundLog(j)
{
   return function(){console.log("===== J ===== "+j);}
}
var increment = 200;

for (var j=0; j<10; j++){

  setTimeout(getBoundLog(j), increment); 

  increment+= 200;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have scope problem I think. You are basically over writing the print function 10 times and because you wait to call the function with setTimeout by the time it gets called the function is actually

```
var print = function(){ console.log("===== J ===== "+10); }
```