# javascript anonymous function with access to variable in creator

Tags: javascript, lambda

I need to access the `i` variable from the loop, in the success function. How do I do that?, can I pass it in to the function?

```
function save(){
    var mods=model.things;
    for (i in mods) {
        var mod= mods[i];
        $.ajax({
            url: "duck"
            type: "put",
            data: JSON.stringify(mod),
            success: function(responce_json) {
                var j=i;   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable binding and loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676362/javascript-variable-binding-and-loop)

Comment: You should read about closures in javascript and what elements cause variable capture and which ones don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another `function` that takes `i` as a parameter thus creating a local copy for each iteration

```
var f = function(i) { 
    var mod= mods[i];
    $.ajax({
        url: "duck"
        type: "put",
        data: JSON.stringify(mod),
        success: function(responce_json) {
            var j=i;   
        }
    });
}
for (iter in mods) {
    f(iter);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
        success: (function(i) { return function(responce_json) {
            var j=i;   
        }})(i)
```

This uses an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to create a closure that will capture the current value of `i`.

Incidently, `for...in` is considered bad practice by a lot of [JavaScript programmers](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/), but if you need to use it, you should probably at least include a check for `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: I went for a different answer because I could read the code. However +1 for the comment on `for…in`, can you tell me the alternative.