# Read and copy file data with FileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to read files from a client through FileReader. I want to create a copy in the browser but I can't figure out how to do it properly.
In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7KnL/16/) i have replicated my problem with the exception that I use a custom class `File` instead of Object, but it's the same result.

If I only select one file, everything is perfectly fine,but as soon as I select multiple files the errors appear. Firstly, all properties of the new Object i create on `line 9` except the `data` is always the last file selected. The function `storeResult` get the result from fileReader OK, but not from my new Object file?

When I click 'Check Array' all objects in the arrays property `data` is now the last file selected. My guess is that it has something to do with scope of some of my variables but I can't figure out where and why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable binding and loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676362/javascript-variable-binding-and-loop)

Comment: You don't capture the current value of `file` for each turn of the loop and so each function winds up storing only the *last* value.  [Here's a fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7KnL/17/) (The only thing I changed was to add an explicit reference to the current file as an argument to your IIFE `(function(file) { /* your code */ }(file));`

Comment: Thanks, this is working! I've never heard of IIFEs before. Is this behaviour Javascript specific? How can I know when i should use this approach? Also, make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. @SeanVieira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [mutating reference bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example):

```
var files = evt.target.files, i, f; 
for (i = 0; f = files[i]; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function onLoad(event) {
        // f is available here
        // but it is not a fixed reference.
        // It changes each time the body
        // of the loop is executed.
        // This function (regardless of the current value of `i`)
        // will only be executed after the containing `for` loop
        // has run to completion.
    };

    // Schedule some work for later
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

The simplest fix is to store a reference to the current `f` in a closure:

```
reader.onload = (function createHandler(currentFile) {
  return function onLoad(event) {
    // f is available here
    // but it is not a fixed reference.

    // `currentFile` is pointing at the value for `f`
    // as it is for this iteration of the loop
    // (that is, it is a fixed reference).
  };

// In order to preserve the state of `f`
// we create a new reference to the value that `f` points
// to for this new function closure and bind it to `currentFile`
// by passing in `f` to our createHandler Immediately Invoked Function Expression
}(f));
```

And then it becomes even clearer what we are doing if we refactor out the factory function:

```
// As a "top-level" function
function createHandler(currentFile) {
  return function onLoad(event) {
    // f is *not* available here.
    // `currentFile` is a reference to the value of
    // whatever is passed in to our `createHandler` function.
    // (that is, it is a fixed reference).
  };
}

// Then, in our handler:
reader.onload = createHandler(f);
```